# Making nonzero elements in grayscale array equal to 1 in 'G' column in an RGB array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rgb, grayscale

So this is a problem that has stumped me for a while now.  It's probably more simple than I think but lets say I have a 2D array that contains grayscale values and I am converting to RGB:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grayscale = [[0, 0, 146, 150], [162, 0, 0, 60]]
gray = np.array(grayscale)

def to_rgb1(gray):
    gray.resize((gray.shape[0], gray.shape[1], 1))
    return np.repeat(gray.astype(np.uint8), 3, 2)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
rgba_img = cmap(gray)
rgb_img = np.delete(rgba_img, 3, 2)

print rgb_img
```

The output of this code is:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.5       ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.5       ]
  [ 0.71790006  1.          0.24984187]
  [ 0.76850095  1.          0.19924099]]

 [[ 0.92030361  1.          0.04743833]
  [ 0.          0.          0.5       ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.5       ]
  [ 0.          0.44117647  1.        ]]]
```

Now lets say I not concerned with `R` and `B` columns.  I know how to make these zero, but what I want to do is make any element that is `nonzero` in the grayscale array equal to `1` in  the `G` column so the output `RGB` array so the output looks like this:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          1.          0.]
  [ 0.          1.          0.]]

 [[ 0.          1.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          0.          0.]
  [ 0.          1.          0.]]]
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to make any element that is `nonzero` in the grayscale array equal to `1` in the `G` channel and set all elements in `R` and `B` channels to `0`, irrespective of the corresponding values in grayscale, one short way would be with [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(gray != 0)[...,None]*[0.0,1,0]
```

Sample run -

```
In [18]: gray
Out[18]: 
array([[  0,   0, 146, 150],
       [162,   0,   0,  60]])

In [19]: (gray != 0)[...,None]*[0.0,1,0]
Out[19]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.]]])
```

---

As another approach with focus on performance, you can initialize with `0s` and then set `1s` -

```
out = np.zeros(gray.shape+(3,))
out[:,:,1] = gray != 0
```